# Accessing the array index

Tags: c, arrays, logic, analytical

I have an array of 255 elements. I need to store 100 values in this array. For example, if there are 3 items rose, red, rat then `arr[0]` should represent `rose`, `arr[1]` should represent `red` and `arr[2]` as `rat`. Then these values are assigned as `arr[0] = 100`, `arr[1] = 200`, `arr[2] = 300`. Now when I want to get the value of `rat` I should be able to get the value directly by accessing its index i.e `arr[2]=300`. My idea is to create macros and assign values to each items and directly access the value in array.
Example:

```
#define ROSE 0 
#define RED 1
#define RAT 2
```

Then directly for `rat` I will say `arr[RAT]` to get the value. Is this a good approach for 100 items?
`ADDITION:`
Now what if the size of values of items vary? For ex. `red` has the 4bytes value and `rat` has 2bytes value, then for `uint8 arr[255];` `red` should starts at `arr[1]` and `rat` should start at `arr[5]`. Does enum still work here?

Comment: If you're only storing 100 values, why does the array have 255 elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [C Enumeration Declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whbyts4t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), `enums`:

```
typedef enum {rose, red, rat} index;
```

Now in your code you can access `arr[rat]` that is == `arr[2]`.

Generally  I avoid macro for this kind of constants (where many constants are of similar types). I think it should be a type with a user defined domain that is `enum`.

> An enumeration consists of a set of named integer constants. An enumeration type declaration gives the name of the (optional) enumeration tag and defines the set of named integer identifiers (called the "enumeration set," "enumerator constants," "enumerators," or "members").

Macro I will prefer for array size:

```
#define SIZE  100;

int arr[SIZE]
```

Thanks to @[junix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863081/junix) to add very nice point in my answer:

It will be nice idea to defined `enum` with to add a last element that give total number of elements, e.g.:

```
typedef enum { rose, 
               red, 
               rat, 
               /* add new elements here */ 
              item_count
        } index;
```

Now my enum domain range is `[0, item_count]`, and we can use `item_count` value for example like:

```
int arr[item_count];
```

And of-course this benefit we don't have with macros!

Comment: I'd even prefer to add a last element called e.g. "item count": `typedef enum {rose, red, rat, /* add new elements here */ item_count} index;` This would allow you to declare an array using a named value, without having to maintain a macro every time you add an item to your enum: `int arr[item_count];`

Comment: Of course. That's why I added this comment. So feel free to do so :-)

Comment: @junix I realized very nice thing you added, I can suggest one more preference of  enum over macros, And learnt a new concept too.. Thanks Junix!

Comment: No issue, Grijesh. I think it's also worth to mention a downside to this concept: In case you don't use the "auto incrementing" of the enumeration, you might have to be careful about how you structure your enumeration. If there are holes in the range, you also have to be aware that you reserve some "extra" elements in the array. But to be honest, most enums I need, don't fall into these categories.

Comment: @junix yes this I had in mind, when you commented me. but really nice idea you given.

Comment: Maintaining 100 separate enums doesn't sound like any less of a pain than maintaining 100 separate macro definitions.

Comment: @JohnBode I was thinking on this that you commented :)

Answer (score 2):

It might be a better approach to use enumeration instead:

```
enum Item {
    ROSE = 0,
    RED = 1,
    RAT = 2
};
arr[RAT]=300
```

`enum` structures are easier to extend (add a new `item`, insert a new item and increment the indexes of the others). If you use macros you'll have to do this manually.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an enum:

```
enum {ROSE, RED, RAT, ...}
```

It better express your intent. You are sure that different tag will get different value. Also if later you use a switch, you'll get warning if you forgot some index.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this sounds like an ideal candidate for a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_Table).

Having to maintain 100 seperate symbols is going to be pain, whether they are macro definitions or enums.